# how to get data from inner join using cdbcriteria in yii?

Tags: yii

This is my SQL. I want to create a `CDbCriteria` in Yii.

```
select us.user_id,u.clientid from user_session us
inner join user u on u.id=us.user_id
where us.auth_token='authtoken0000000001'
```

I tried this, but gives the wrong result. I also defined a relation `related` in my `user_session` model for this.

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
 $criteria->select = "user_id,user.clientid as client_id";
 $criteria->condition='auth_token="'.$token.'"';
 $clientIdarray = UserSession::model()->with('related')->find($criteria);
```

Comment: Why don't you use params for data binding?

Comment: Can you give more details?
What is the problem? (The wrong result with client_id?).
Put the relation with 'related' please.

Comment: I want to execute this query-->select us.user_id,u.clientid from user_session us
inner join user u on u.id=us.user_id
where us.auth_token='authtoken11111' with cdbcriteria

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataprovider=New CActiveDataProvider('Bla',
    array(
    'criteria'=>array(      
      'order'=>'id ASC',
      'with'=>array(
        'user',
        ),
    'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',               
    'condition'=>'user.auth_token = '.$token,
        )
        ));
```

Just an example how to do dataprovider init.
`$criteria->with` do what you need.
This topic will help. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr